# Meteor microservice with MySQL backend

Tags: mysql, meteor

So I just successfully built my first meteor mysql app using [numtel/meteor-mysql](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql).

It works like a charm but I've got one problem - I am currently researching for a bigger project with different customers who have different backends. So the backend mysql structure will definitely change a lot.

The frontend and the majority of code although will be the same. So of course I would like to be able to patch all this code as easy as possible. If some of the backend code always changes, this is not possible as every "meteor node package" will be different for every customer.

My idea was to have a meteor microservice which handles the backend mysql calls and provides the data to a main app (also written in Meteor, which is the same for every customer) via DDP.
With mongo this is possible as shown [here](http://justmeteor.com/blog/microservices-with-meteor/) and [here](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ddp).

Does anybody have an idea on how to do all this with a mysql backend while using the mentioned package?

Or does anybody have an idea on how to achieve my goal of easy maintainability as described above without the need for a microservice?

Comment: as opposed to having people read other articles to help you (I did click on them), can you crystallize it for us. Think [Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers to everyone but it turns out I should have just read the docs more carefully, as [numtel/meteor-mysql](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql) provides the DDP mysql subscription out of the box.

So I am now running two seperate meteor apps which communicate via the standard DDP package. The "API" meteor app is server only and runs numtels package to make the SQL calls. The main app uses the same package for the subscription to have a reactive data binding.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you need. The basic idea is to build a separate app that exposes some sort of [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

For Meteor, there's a very nice package that helps build maintainable APIs, see [`nimble:restivus` package](https://atmospherejs.com/nimble/restivus).

The next thing to do is to separate the REST API from your monolithic app and perhaps deploy it as another Meteor instance, be it the same server or a new one.

And finally you will have to consume your new API from you app to send and receive data that is stored somewhere in MySQL DB. Just use `HTTP.call`s from [`http` package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/http).